# How to add CoSign Web Agent XML tag for 2 Signature Fields?

Tags: cosign-api

I can test sign document with 1 Define Signature 
but How to add 2 define signature in XML Tag ?

http://webagentdev.arx.com:88/testApp/

Tab : Define a signature field

Thank you for advance

Answer (score 0):

[Disclosure: I work for CoSign]

In response to your question, our engineering group has investigated the issue. For the current release (ver 7.2), the CoSign Web App product, via its Web Agent API, will only create one signature field. The `<SigProfiles>` element should only contain, at most, one `<SigProfile>` child element.

**Creating multiple Signature Fields**

The Web Agent can handle multiple signature fields, the issue is how to create them. We recommend using the *[CoSign Signature SOAP API](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.2/Default.htm#doc_7.2/CoSign%20Signature%20SOAP.htm)*

Another advantage of using the CoSign Signature SOAP network api is that it enables you to position the signature fields by using Locator Tags instead of using specific xy positioning. See the method `SAPISignatureFieldLocatorEnumInit` available via the CoSign Signature SOAP `Sign` call.